Why are there more connections in my RDS database than expected, despite HikariCP's configuration in Spring Boot?
I am using Spring Boot with JPA and HikariCP as the connection pool for my application. My application.properties file is configured as follows:

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect




spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=50000
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=60000
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG


However, I am noticing an issue with the number of active connections in my Amazon RDS database. The logs from HikariCP indicate that there are only 5 idle connections in the pool, and no active requests are being made. But when I check the RDS database, I see more than 5 connections, sometimes exceeding the maximum pool size I have set (20 connections).
I expected the number of connections in RDS to not exceed the value of spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size, but it seems that there are still more connections than expected. Here are a few key points:
HikariCP Logs: The HikariCP logs show that there are only 5 idle connections in the pool, and no active queries are being executed.
RDS Connections: The RDS instance shows more than 5 connections (often more than the configured pool size).
Possible Causes: I’m unsure whether this is due to connection leakage, idle connections not being closed properly, or some other factor. I have set the leak-detection-threshold to 60 seconds, but the problem persists.
I’ve tried adjusting the max-lifetime, idle-timeout, and other settings, but the issue remains.
Question: Why is the number of connections in my RDS database higher than expected despite the HikariCP settings, and what steps can I take to ensure that the pool size is respected?
2024-11-24T19:16:01.029Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-14 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@34e8ab26: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2024-11-24T19:16:01.163Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@4e06539b
2024-11-24T19:16:01.193Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Connection not added, stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:04.432Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-14 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@596186a: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2024-11-24T19:16:04.569Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7f027cc6
2024-11-24T19:16:04.573Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-14 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@54c75469: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2024-11-24T19:16:04.599Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Connection not added, stats (total=4, active=0, idle=4, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:04.721Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2e29acd4
2024-11-24T19:16:04.751Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Connection not added, stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:05.252Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [nnection closer] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-14 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@20c9190d: (connection has passed maxLifetime)
2024-11-24T19:16:05.386Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@66979cbd
2024-11-24T19:16:05.417Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Connection not added, stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:16.012Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-13 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-13 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:16.012Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-13 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-13 - After cleanup  stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:16.012Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-13 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-13 - Fill pool skipped, pool has sufficient level or currently being filled.
2024-11-24T19:16:24.450Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-14 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:24.451Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-14 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - After cleanup  stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2024-11-24T19:16:24.451Z DEBUG 667651 --- [voting-system] [-14 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-14 - Fill pool skipped, pool has sufficient level or currently being filled.



Can you explain a bit more about your usage of RDS? Do you have a proxy setup? Where specifically are you getting the information for current connections from?

Is your application the only one connecting? Do you have multiple instances of the application (as each has its own connection pool). Check where the connections are coming from (I don't know the console but you can probably see some IP address of process name that is connecting?).

I deployed the app as a WAR file on the server's default Tomcat.
The problem occurred because I didn’t stop Tomcat before applying a new version of the app as a WAR file.
I simply replaced the old WAR file with the new one while Tomcat was still running.
I don't know how this solved the problem, but Tomcat restarted automatically after just replacing the file.
